# While using .fetch, can I chain together existing .fetch functions into a larger synchronous query?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I know how to chain all of this together into one function. I am confused on how I'd incorporate the following function's return value into another?

```
function queryPlayers() {
    fetch("foo", apiParams)
        .then(res => { 
            if(res.ok){ return res.json() }
            else { return fetch("backup_bar", apiParams)
                .then(res => { return res.json() }
            )}
        })
        .then(playerData => { return playerData })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

All I want to do is take `playerData`, or the JSON I receive and throw it into another function as an argument once the promise resolves. I'm quite new to arrow functions and promises and I feel I just am missing something.

```
function getExtraData(playerData){
  fetch("some_foo" + playerData)
    .then(newData => doStuff())
}
```

For reference, here is what I ended up doing as a super basic answer to the question:

```
function queryPlayers() {
    console.log("Querying players...");
    return fetch("https://api-v2.royaleapi.com/top/players", apiParams)
        .then(res => { 
            if(res.ok){ return res.json() }
            else { return fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/players.json", apiParams)
                .then(res => res.json()
            )}
        })
        .then(playerData => { 
            return playerData;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
function queryData(){
    queryPlayers()
    .then(data => console.log(data))
}
$(function(){
    queryData();
});
```

Comment: Yes you are just missing a `return` at the beginning of your `queryPlayers` function:  `function queryPlayers() {
    return fetch( "foo",...` then you just need to `queryPlayers().then( getExtraData )`

Comment: Wow, I implemented that it and it worked great.... I wasn't aware it needed that extra return in there,

Comment: Your `.then(playerData => { return playerData })` is redundant. You can omit this altogether.